# AWS VPC security group inbound rule issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I am trying to add default security group inbound rule for some 500+ elastic IPs of external gateway we used for network deployment to allow traffic in vpc where
E.g. As below

```
192.168.0.64
```

Terraform block to add ingress rule to security group which is not working:

```
resource "aws_default_security_group" "default" {
vpc_id = aws_vpc.demo_vpc.id

ingress = [ {
  cidr_blocks = "192.168.0.64"
  description = "Allowed security rules"
  from_port = 22
  ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
  prefix_list_ids = []
  protocol = "tcp"
  security_groups = [ aws_vpc.demo_vpc.default_security_group_id ]
  self = false
  to_port = 22
} ]

egress = [ {
  cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
  description = "Allow All"
  from_port = 0
  ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
  prefix_list_ids = []
  protocol = "all"
  security_groups = [ aws_vpc.demo_vpc.default_security_group_id ]
  self = false
  to_port = 0
} ]
}
```

I get it, ingress rules needs cidr blocks and does not accept specific IP. What is the way to allow only specific IP traffic in given VPC.

Expectation is only 500+ IPs should be able to access server within VPC. Those 500 IPs are completely different to each other i mean, cidr perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [/32 CIDR](https://superuser.com/a/1473260/4377) points to a single IP, so that's what you'll have to append to your IPs.

```
cidr_blocks = ["192.168.0.64/32"]
```

Comment: Also note, that by default you can only have 60 rules in a security group - although you can request increase: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html